# Right side of Earpod dead but the buttons are functioning. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: audio, apple-music, ear-phones

Okay,the jack is plugged in properly. The problem is, while the audio is coming from the left Earbud, the right Earbud is dead. However, in Apple earpods, the controller (volume and on-off button) is in the right wire. This suggests, that the right side *is* getting the current. But, no audio is coming out. It was working fine all this morning, I listened to songs but since the evening, the right side is dead. Can you suggest a troubleshoot?

Comment: try moving the plug in and out slowly to see if you can hear

Answer (score 1):

If you're still in your first year or have Applecare on your device you got the earpods with, call Applecare, they will set you up with a replacement pair.

Answer (score 0):

The controls use the same wire as the microphone, which is independent from the right earbud. Most likely the problem lies in a disconnection in the right earbud itself.

Comment: I have tried to clean the bud surfaces. Thought might be moisture could have entered, so kept it in a dry place. Anything else that can be done?